# MMENU doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, mmenu

I followed the official mmenu tutorial but I can't get it working. The menu doesn't appear.

my html file content :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Mmenu demo</title>
        <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/jquery.mmenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/static/css/jquery.mmenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/static/css/mmenu-demo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="/static/js/mmenu-demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper>
            <div id="content" class="content">
                <div id="box" class="box">
                <div id="title" class="title">mmenu demo</div>
                <div id="desc" class="desc">A menu should appear on the left</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Street views</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Shootings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

my custom javascript file **mmenu-demo.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").mmenu();
});
```

my custom css file **mmenu-demo.css** (just to run the demo)

```
.content{   
    padding:1em;
    text-align:center;
}

.box{
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    width:30%;
}

.title{
    font-size:2.5em;
    font-family:"arial";
    color:white;    
    padding:1em;
    background-color:black;
}

.desc{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:1em;
    color:white;
    padding:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:30%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just missing a quote.

This:

```
<div id="wrapper>
```

should be this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

Also, as Emmanuel Brunet stated:

```
$("#menu").mmenu();
```

should be:

```
$("#menu").trigger("open");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, that's correct but it's a typing error and not the problem root. I just found out now that in the mmenu-demo.js javascript it lakes a $("#menu").trigger("open"); statement ... it's a mmenu documentation lake !